# Java Collections Wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define a List object and then add objects to it using the code below:

```
List<? extends File> newFiles = new ArrayList<? extends File>();
```

When I try to define it like that, I get a compiler error

> Cannot instantiate the type `ArrayList<? extends File>`

whereas

```
List<? extends File> newFiles = new ArrayList<File>()
```

seems to be valid.  It is not clear why.

File is a bean object I created-not the object belonging to the Java API.

Comment: Because you cannot instantiate a wildcard type, only a reference to it. Please don't get into the habit of naming classes the same as ones commonly used in the Java API.

Answer (score 6):

You're not capable of directly instantiating a wildcard type.  In this case, that would be `? extends File`.

What you can do is simply use `File`, as `extends` implies an upper-bound relationship (you're guaranteed that the elements in that collection are at *least* `File`)...

```
List<? extends File> newFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
```

...or you could use the diamond notation in Java 7+, which is more idiomatic nowadays.

```
List<? extends File> newFiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

After a bit of a rethink, are you sure you want that wildcard?  With generics, if you're using bound types, the rule to remember is **PECS** - Producer **Extends**, Consumer **Super**.  As a producer, that list cannot be added to any further, in spite of the fact that it's empty.

It may be better to do away with the generic type bound altogether for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Makato.The wildcard was part of the method of the API.Thank you for your response.